# Sorting Special Characters in Javascript (Æ)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, special-characters

I'm trying to sort an array of objects based on the objects' `name` property. Some of the names start with 'Æ', and I'd like for them to be sorted as though they were 'Ae'. My current solution is the following:

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aName = a.name.replace(/Æ/gi, 'Ae'),
      bName = b.name.replace(/Æ/gi, 'Ae');
  return aName.localeCompare(bName);
});
```

I feel like there should be a better way of handling this without having to manually replace each and every special character. Is this possible?

I'm doing this in Node.js if it makes any difference.

Comment: I don't think so. You could also create your own abecedary which includes "Æ" in the position that you want. But then it will be treated as a single character, so the effect will be different than treating it as two characters.

Comment: Why would you want it to be sorted that way?  'Æ' normally comes after 'Z'.

Comment: @PaulButcher I'm trying to match something that has already established 'Æ' as essentially being 'Ae'. I also personally think that placing 'Æ' anywhere else would be unintuitive.

Comment: RE the former - If Æ is AE in the environment you are using, then why not change it to AE straight away?  RE the latter - in most of those modern languages that use it, alphabetic ordering  places it after Z (or Y in languages without a Z)  Therefore, the intuitive place to put it is after Z (or Y).  If you want to move it to somewhere abnormal, you'd have to do it the same way as with any other letter.

Comment: @PaulButcher In this case, with Æ, if Æ properly belongs after Z, then I understand I would have to do a replacement like I am. Ignoring Æ for the moment - `'À'.localeCompare('Z');` returns `102`, saying that À comes after Z. That _definitely_ seems unintuitive. I'd expect À to be equal to A for sorting purposes. iOS has the sorting function `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` which puts Æ near Ae and À near A which makes me feel like what I'm asking for isn't completely ridiculous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no simpler way. Unfortunately, even the way described in the question is too simple, at least if portability is of any concern.

The `localeCompare` method is by definition implementation-dependent, and it usually depends on the UI language of the underlying operating system, though it may also differ between browsers (or other JavaScript implementations) in the same computer. It can be hard to find any documentation on it, so even if you aim at writing non-portable code, you might need to do a lot of testing to see which collation order is applied. Cf. to [Sorting strings is much harder than you thought!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127913/sorting-strings-is-much-harder-than-you-thought)

So to have a controlled and portable comparison, you need to code it yourself, unless you are lucky enough to find someone else’s code that happens to suit your needs. On the positive side, the *case conversion* methods are one of the few parts of JavaScript that are localization-ready: they apply Unicode case mapping rules, so e.g. `'æ'.toUpperCase()` yields Æ in any implementation.

In general, sorting strings requires a complicated function that applies specific sorting rules as defined for a language or by some other rules, such as the Pan-European sorting rules (intended for multilingual content). But if we can limit ourselves to sorting rules that deal with just a handful of letters in addition to Ascii, we can use code like the following simplified sorting for German (extract from by book [Going Global with JavaScript and Globalize.js](http://www.bytelevelbooks.com/books/global_javascript.html)):

```
String.prototype.removeUmlauts = function () {
  return this.replace(/Ä/g,'A').replace(/Ö/g,'O').replace(/Ü/g,'U');
}; 
function alphabetic(str1, str2) {
  var a = str1.toUpperCase().removeUmlauts();
  var b = str2.toUpperCase().removeUmlauts();
  return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
}
```

You could adds other mappings, like `replace(/Æ/gi, 'Ae')`, to this, after analyzing the characters that may appear and deciding how to deal with them. Removing diacritic marks (e.g. mapping É to E) is simplistic but often good enough, and surely better than leaving it to implementations to decide whether É is somewhere after Z. And at least you would get consistent results across implementations, and you would see what things go wrong and need fixing, instead of waiting for other users complain that your code sorts all wrong (in their environment).

Comment: Thanks - nice answer and links. I'll forego localeCompare and move to something like you described.